# Android sharedPreferences set default values issue

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using some activities in my project. One of them is extended from PreferenceActivity. 
I have a CheckBoxPreference and an EditTextPreference, I can get the values from all the other activities using:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
pref = sharedPrefs.getString("edit_text_pref", "error");
```

but when I open my app the values must be set to default, therefore I'm using:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().clear().commit();
```

in my main activity. 
All should be ok, but if I try to get the preference before to set it from the preferences menu I get "error" and not the default value that I set in the xml preference file.
If i comment the `getDefaultSharedPreferences` line it works fine but obviously when i open the app I get the old preferences.
How can i bypass this problem?

Comment: do not use `getDefaultSharedPreferences`, use `SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG,
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in both classes

Comment: I use this for setting default values: PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the default value itself, i.e, "error" because with Preferences, when you get the value of any preference then you need to specify a value that is to be returned if the preference is not set before. In your case, as you are setting the default value to "error" in here `pref = sharedPrefs.getString("edit_text_pref", "error");` so thats what you get as the default value.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29

Yout must be using this  `setDefaultValues (Context context, int resId, boolean readAgain)` some thing like

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

Take a good look at the note section in the parameters. This is concering read again
Parameters

`context`   The context of the shared preferences.

`resId` The resource ID of the preference XML file.

### readAgain   Whether to re-read the default values. If false, this method sets the default values only if this method has never been called in the past (or if the `KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES` in the default value shared preferences file is false). To attempt to set the default values again bypassing this check, set readAgain to true.

### Note: this will NOT reset preferences back to their default values. For that functionality, use `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` and clear it followed by a call to this method with this parameter set to true

So I guess after clearing it you need to set it to default by passing the readAgain as true

something like

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().clear().commit();
 PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I tought the "error" was the value used if there was an error reading the value and not if the value was not set!!

Thank you it should be work, I'm going to try